# Increase values in array

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, arrays, smart-contract-wallets

I am increasing the value at a particular index in Solidity but it is giving me bad instruction error.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Please check the sample contract for reference:

```
pragma solidity >0.6.0;

contract abs{
    uint256[] public amounts;
    
    function contractParams(uint256 index, uint256 val) external{
        amounts[index] = amounts[index] + val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element index is out of range from arrays length. It will revert.
To push value to array, use `amounts.push(x)`